# Multiple wins with different races, but only 1 "Win of day"

Tags: starcraft-2

I'd like to unlock ranked games for free on a new account, so I need 10 "Win of day".

The in-game text suggests that you can win multiple "Win of day" (one with each race). I've won multiple games (1 unranked, then multiple "Versus A.I." with a different race) but I have only 1 "Win of day".

Is it a bug or are there additional conditions that I should know?

P.S. : I know there may be a minimum length for the game to count (2 min 30) but I was over this.

Comment: I've also searched about this in the official technical support forum, but any question asked about this question have received no answer for years.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft2/comments/7d72uv/do_you_need_10_wins_versus_ai_or_unranked_each/), it only conuts one win per day for the ranked unlock, so you have to wait at least 10 days.

Comment: Well, I've read this reddit, and I can read : "I think you can get 1 "first win" of the day with each race though (T,P,Z,R), so only 3 days to unlock ranked." and then someone says it's not true because he played 2v2 and it didnt work (but maybe only 2v2 is excluded).

Comment: This reddit post is more explicit about it though : https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/7dc0v3/f2p_first_win_of_the_day/ Maybe I just misread the text, because it says for unranked unlocking : "This can only be earned on one race per day" by opposition to bonus xp which can be earned for each race and each day.